# Do I need to worry about crop factor or sensor size when comparing wide angle lenses for the same camera?

Tags: lens, wide-angle, sensor-size, field-of-view, crop-factor

I want to upgrade my wide angle lens to wider, but I don't understand well which lens will give me wide enough angle. I have Nikon D7000 and Nikkor 18-70mm, but I'm thinking of upgrade Tokina 11-16 or Rokinon 14mm.

I watched some reviews on YouTube, and they said that Rokinon 14mm on crop sensor will give 18mm or something like that — it's hard for me to understand this. So how do I choose a lens that will give me wider angle on my D7000 than my 18-70 gives?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is "angle of view" in photography?](http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/5917/what-is-angle-of-view-in-photography)

Comment: Possibly related: [Does wide angle equivalent in crop sensor skew image?](http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/48337/does-wide-angle-equivalent-in-crop-sensor-skew-image)

Comment: @mattdm I wasn't sure about this being a duplicate or not as most of the crop-factor related questions boil down to how one lens is different on different bodies (with different sensors), but this question seems to ask how different lenses compare on the same body. Figuring out what an equivalent focal length is seems to have caused some confusion, which motivated the question in the first place. It does not however appear to be necessary to answer it. Either way, those questions you linked to are a great resource and definitely worth a look.

Comment: Yeah. Some of the other crop factor questions like 
[Is the kit lens focal length specified for APS-C or FF?](http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/3338/is-the-kit-lens-focal-length-specified-for-aps-c-or-ff) and [Why do Full Frame lenses and crop body lenses exhibit the same crop factor when used on a crop body camera?](http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/38899/why-do-full-frame-lenses-and-crop-body-lenses-exhibit-the-same-crop-factor-when) may also be helpful.

Comment: You might also consider the Tokina 11-20mm. It's a little bit pricier, but the image quality is demonstrably better than the 11-16mm II.

Answer (score 3):

> they said that Rokinon 14mm on crop sensor will give 18mm or smth like this, it's hard for me to understand this

The calculation that they are doing there is to calculate the full frame equivalent, which is basically multiplying the focal length by some factor.
The full frame equivalent of the lens is not of interest to you, because the factor is the same for every lens. After multiplying every focal length with the same factor, the widest lens will still be the widest, so there's no point in doing that calculation in the first place.

**Simply compare the focal lengths.**

The Tokina 11-16 offers the widest focal length with 11mm. Both the Tokina and the Rokinon are wider than your Nikkor lens, because both have shorter focal lengths than 18mm.

Comment: Yea but their 11mm is value for full-frame sensor or crop?

Comment: @Arkadi neither of both. 11mm is 11mm. The focal length is a property of the lens. You might use it on differently sized sensors which gives a different field of view (among other things), but as I stated in my answer, there's no point in asking what it would be like on a different sensor, because **you are comparing lenses for the same sensor**. Analogy: if you want to know which of 2 people can jump higher, it doesn't matter if each of them would jump to a different hight on a planet with lower gravity. All you need is a comparison with the same gravity value.

Comment: I was confused about what he's saying on 2:25, something about angles and widness, https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_TSrFKLzsrQ

Answer (score 3):

**Just look at focal lengths.**

Crop factors and equivalency really don't matter very much if you're not using two different formats. That a 14mm lens on a 1.65 crop looks like 21mm on a full-frame doesn't help you if you don't know what 21mm on full frame looks like.  The crop conversion thing is only going to be helpful for you if/when you add an FX camera body to your arsenal, and you realize you're going to need a lens that does, say, what your 18-55 does on your D7000, so you know the focal length range you want in an FX lens has to cover 27-83mm (18-55x1.5).

If you only have the single camera body, then just judge the scene coverage of a lens by its focal length. The shorter it is, the wider it goes. You may also want to use [a focal length simulator](http://imaging.nikon.com/lineup/lens/simulator/) that can show you what specific focal lengths look like on a DX body, if you're having trouble visualizing because you've never used those lengths before.

In my experience, an ultrawide zoom is much nicer than a prime if you aren't sure about focal lengths and are new to using ultrawides. When you get down to the smaller focal lengths, a single millimeter change in the focal length can be a much larger change than you're expecting, and you can't get the same perspective by simply walking forwards/backwards. Just my opinion, but I'd definitely save up for the 11-16/2.8 over the Samyang/Rokinon 14mm if I were shooting a crop body. I'd only go for the Samyang 14 if I were shooting full frame and knew I needed/liked that focal length and didn't mind the PITAness of an all-manual lens with no electronic communication; otherwise, on full frame, I'd probably save up pennies for the Tokina 16-28/2.8 or an OEM 16-35.

Answer (score 0):

No. The cropfactor is only to differentiate the angle of view between a fullframe body and a crop body. 
Best way to explain is if you have a full frame, the crop would be a digital zoom ( since you use a smaller part of the sensor, or a smaller sensor in a different body ).
On the same body it does play a role. So 11-16 mm is wider than 18-70 and the 14mm the middle of 11-16mm.

There you go : )