# What is the conversion between focal length and times zoom?

Tags: zoom, focal-length

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I convert lens mm to optical zoom times?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/13717/how-do-i-convert-lens-mm-to-optical-zoom-times)

What is the conversion between focal length in mm (e.g. 50mm) and x zoom (e.g. 20x) commonly used in compact cameras? Is there an equivalence or ar they not able to be compared?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> What is the conversion between focal length and times zoom?

There is no "industry standard formal definition" of the term 20x etc **BUT**
Almost universal usage is that this is the ratio between the maximum and minimum focal lengths available from the lens.

So eg an 18mm - 90mm is 90/18 = 5:1 = 5x.

The extreme available DSLR DX lens so far (as far as I know) is 18mm -300mm = 300/18 = 15.55:1 ~= 16x

"Ultrazoom" compact cameras and video cameras with small sensor areas need correspondingly less glass to achieve a given 35mm-equivalent focal length*, and quality is less to far-less of an issue than with SLRs, so far larger max to min  zoom ratios are possible and available with these cameras than with SLRs.

---

- "35-mm equivalent" means that if the image on the sensor is the same as would have been achieved with a "35mm" film camera on standard sized 35mm film with an xx mm lens then the lens is said to xx mm in 35mm-equivalent.
  eg If a point & shoot camera lens when set to 15mm focal length, produces on the P&S sensor an image with the same content as would be produced on a 35mm film camera sensor when a 50mm lens was used then the lens is said to be set to '50mm, '35mm equivalent' "

Comment: Yeah I know. I have the Ret Butler attitude as far as the mindset of the downvoter, but it's hard to imagine what photo-space they live in. It could be XXxxxx who from his high perch digs up my past answers to downvote them (why I know not) or XxxxXxxx who seems to have a general aversion to my answers. But, what good does this do other people?

Answer (score 5):

"times zoom" is the ratio between the focal length when zoomed all the way in and the focal length when zoomed all the way out.

So a 17-70mm lens is a x4 lens (70/17 = 4.1) but a 100-400mm is also a x4 lens (400/100 = 4).

So, the "times zoom" number tells us how big the range is for a specific camera/lens but tells us absolutely nothing about the actual focal length (or the 35mm equivalent focal length).