# How to calculate the zoom power (X factor) for a lens?

Tags: focal-length, camera-basics

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I convert lens mm to optical zoom times?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/13717/how-do-i-convert-lens-mm-to-optical-zoom-times)

How can I obtain the "X factor" for a lens?

I thought that to get the "X factor" I had to divide the largest focal length by the smallest one: using this my 18-55mm lens is a 3x one, and the 100-300mm would also be a 3x one, even if they are obviously very different lenses.