# Tamron AF 70-300mm f/4.0-5.6 Di LD Macro Zoom Lens for Canon Digital SLR Cameras for Canon Rebel T3i

Tags: lens, equipment-recommendation, canon-600d, macro-lenses

does [Tamron AF 70-300mm f/4.0-5.6 Di LD Macro Zoom Lens for Canon Digital SLR Cameras](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B000EXOXVA) suite my Canon 600D? and is it good for macro photography?

I'm looking for a cheap option (under 200$) to shoot macro photos using Canon Rebel T3i, and I came through this lens.

Comment: You meant "Macro photography"

Comment: "Micro photography" means three possible things a) photographs through a microscope, b) photographs which _require_ a microscope (or at least magnification) to view, or c) a synonym for macro photography. Presumably macro photography is meant here given the lens.

Comment: Akram, you're getting downvotes because: 1) you're asking multiple questions in one question, making it difficult to answer canonically in a way that's helpful to others; 2) you didn't bother to capitalize the first letter of your post or make your final sentence even really make sense, and you've been around here for a while and should be able to do that; and, probably, 3) the ambiguity with micro/macro is possibly indicative of lack of research, and although that alone doesn't bother me, I _do_ notice that a _very high_ percentage of your questions are duplicates or near-duplicates.

Comment: (Likewise, "Is this lens, currently made and sold by a major 3rd-party lens company as compatible with Canon cameras, compatible with my current Canon camera?" shows a lack of research. It's okay to have confusion about that and ask for help, but it's _better_ if you can explain why you're concerned that it might not work.)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I choose a macro lens for a Canon APS-C camera?](http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/932/how-do-i-choose-a-macro-lens-for-a-canon-aps-c-camera)

Comment: @mattdm I Appreciate your explanation about how to form a question. The question doesn't have multiple questions, it basically says that I'm looking for a Macro lens and I found this option and I'm considering it cause it's cheap, so will it suite Canon 600D and will it produce photos with good quality?
Second, I didn't realize that capitalizing is an issue in StachExchange at all, I agree it looks nicer but I didn't know it's a must and I can be down voted because of that!

Comment: @mattdm Third, confusing a word with another doesn't mean that I didn't bother myself with searching, I "bothered" myself googling for a lens which by the way has "Macro" in its name, anyway it's my fault.
Fourth, I think it's really fine to ask if a 3rd party lens will be supported for my camera.
Fifth, I looked at the question your are claiming as a duplicate and it's a general question, it's not specific for the lens I'm asking for.
I do really appreciate what you're doing to keep this forum useful. Keep it up

Comment: It's pretty funny that you say "it's just one question: this _and_ this other thing". :) Since this lens comes in different mount versions but is essentially the same, there's no particular reason but the linkage of these things that the question couldn't be useful to a Pentax or Nikon user.

Comment: As for taking the time to punctuate or spell correctly: it's not mandatory, but it _is_ the goal. If you're asking a lot of questions — particularly ones where there's other reasons to think "hey, why didn't they just search for and look on the [Tamron lens compatibility chart](http://www.tamron-usa.com/lenses/prod/assets/pdfs/slr_compatability_chart.pdf)?" — investing time to make the question nice makes people (not just me!) more likely to feel helpful rather than sighing and hitting the down arrow. (P.S. There _is_ extra latitude for non-native speakers, but _shift_ works in any language.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Tamron AF 70-300mm f/4.0-5.6 Di LD Macro lens is compatible with the Canon 600D or T3i. The Di designation actually means that it is compatible with both full frame and crop sensor cameras such as the 600D.

It is termed "macro lens", so yes it will *do* macro photography, but it is not a true 1:1 macro lens. It has a maximum magnification in the macro mode of 1:2, and only 1:4 without the mode. What this means is that the classical term "macro lens" does not apply to this lens. Instead, it has the capability to achieve a large subject size, but not quite what a dedicated macro lens can achieve. I would consider this lens to be very useful in macro photography though.

If you are looking for a lens under $200 in this range, that also does macro to a degree, this is a viable option and will get it done for you.

Comment: I think for this answer to be correct it needs to discuss 1:2 magnification.

Comment: @mattdm - Thanks for the tip, I did leave out some important details before.

Answer (score 2):

I had this lens and for the real Macro photography it's nearly useless.

It's good for shooting "details", but not real macro. It's far too hard to frame and focus on small objects.

Very long focal length, and very long lens barrel, with a very high "minimum focus distance" of almost one metre from the camera's sensor.

You'd be much better off getting a proper Macro lens, like the 90 or 100mm f2.8

Answer (score 1):

Macro lens is a lens that gives you 1:1 magnification or more (i.e size of the object on the sensor is its real size). This lens is not a true macro lens.
For under $200, your best bet is extension tubes.

Answer (score 1):

Actually if you have a kit lens, the **FREE** option is **reverse lens macro technique.**

Here is a link for a nice tutorial with some good photo illustration of why this works:
http://stephenelliot.com/2007/05/15/reverse-lens-macro-photography-tutorial/

Edit: All lenses can be used this way, I mentioned the kit lens only because it is the cheapest and people using this technique usually try it out on their kit lens. However feel free to try this on other lenses too.